# Unable to access field within JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following code in React JSX, and am trying access the fields inside my poolInfo array. I know the first element exists because I can log it, but trying to access any of the element fields gives undefined.

```
createMatches(){
        let id=1;
        let matches=[];
        let poolInfo=this.state.poolInfo;
        let pools = this.props.tournament.pools;
        for (let i=0; i<pools; i++) {
            console.log(poolInfo[i]);
            console.log(poolInfo[i].poolTeams);
        }

    }
```

I've looked into how to access both array Elements and objects in javascript, but I just can't seem to get any of the internal fields. Can someone explain what is happening here?

[image: DataStructure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`poolTeams` seems to be inside a `pool` attribute.

You can just change your code to:

```js
createMatches(){
  let id=1;
  let matches=[];
  let poolInfo=this.state.poolInfo;
  let pools = this.props.tournament.pools;
  for (let i=0; i<pools; i++) {
    console.log(poolInfo[i].pool);
    console.log(poolInfo[i].pool.poolTeams);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over pools without specifiying the length.

```
 for (let i=0; i<pools; i++) {
```

should be:

```
 for (let i=0; i  < pools.length; i++) {
```

or

```
 for (let pool of pools) {
```

Comment: How do we know `this.props.tournament.pools` is not a number?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava that's possible. In that case, d4vsanchez's solution is probably right in that he's accessing poolTeams incorrectly.

Comment: yes pools was a number. I believe  d4vsanchez's solution is the correct one for my problem.